# Fluent Nhibernate Conventions And Setting LazyLoad(Laziness.NoProxy)

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have been setting my references to .LazyLoad(Laziness.NoProxy) on each Reference in my mapping files.

I wondered if i can set this by default via a convention in my fluent setup?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the *IReferenceConvention* is what you need:

```
public class ReferencesConvention : IReferenceConvention
{
    public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
    {
        instance.LazyLoad(Laziness.NoProxy);
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you add the convention to your Fluent mappings:

```
config.Mappings(m => 
        {
            // ......
            // Adding your Fluent mappings

            // Add all the custom conventions
            m.FluentMappings.Conventions.Add<ReferencesConvention>();
        });
```